# Sub/superscripts convention $U_i^{n}$ in numerical PDEs vs. differential geometry

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

**Short Version.** 
When solving a time-stepping 1D PDE, should I store solution $U_i^n$ in the $n$th row and $i$th column of a matrix?

**Longer Version.** 
In numerical PDEs, e.g. LeVeque, *Finite Difference Methods for Ordinary and Partial Differential Equations*, the term $U_i^n$ means, "The approximate solution at time point $t_n$ and grid point $x_i$." In, linear algebra with summation notation, e.g. Lee, *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*, it means, "The entry in row $n$ and column $i$ of matrix $U$." Now, it happens that in numerical PDEs, the solution $U$ is stored as matrix $U$. So I'm wondering if the intention behind the numerical PDE notation is that the solution at $(t_n, x_i)$ should be stored in entry $(n, i)$, i.e. in row $n$ column $i$?

I ask because making the notation match between these disciplines seems intuitive. It also means that the spatial dimension is laid out left-to-right, like an $x$-axis, and then time progresses as you read down the matrix, which is also very intuitive. But in implementation, it means that time point $U^n$ is stored as a row vector, where as numerical algorithms involving matrix multiplication use $U^n$ as a column vector.

For example, in a method that is backward Euler in time, we need to solve $MU^{n+1} = U^n$. To implement this literally as written, a solver in MATLAB would need the code:

```
for j = 1:N
    X = U(j,:).';
    Y = M\X;
    U(j+1,:) = Y.';
end
```

In this code, the $j$th row of the solution $U$ is transposed into column vector $X$ and column vector $Y$ is solved for, which is then transposed back into a row and stored in the $(j+1)$-th row of $U$. All the transposition seems like unnecessary confusion in the code, but on the other hand reversing notational conventions seems confusing too.

Comment: The standard convention for a matrix is that the superscript labels the rows and the subscript labels the columns. I think this is true in most fields of math.

Comment: Thank you. I am asking if, in practice, people actually do store the solution $U_i^n$ using this standard convention, since doing means additional manipulation of the solution matrix in the implementation. Any ideas?